# Open Mailchimp subscription form next to button on click Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to open a MailChimp simple subscription form (email and submit) right next to a button on my Wordpress page.

I just want to have a simple button that says Newsletter and when you click on it the small form appears next to it or bellow it.

I can´t find a plugin to do just this and I wonder if anybody knows any or if I have to do this by coding some js or even a new plugin.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://codepen.io/peternguyen/pen/hICga/

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [documentation](https://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/add-a-signup-form-to-your-website) here on how to generate a form embed code.

Then set it's `display:none`. Then you can use an onclick to fire it.

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function(){

  $('#mailChimpForm').fadeIn();

});
```

Comment: Where in Wordpress would I need to put this code to work in the index page?

Comment: ... in the index page?

Comment: I am sorry I am just not use to use js in Wordpress. You mean in the editor in the html view?

Comment: No, in your template files.

Comment: I´ve added this js in my index.php and I have given the button the #myButto IDand the form the #mailChimpForm ID but doesn´t seem to be working.    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myButton').on('click', function(){
  $('#mailChimpForm').fadeIn();
});

Comment: Please, close this question. You do not understand basic code so you won't be able to do this.